# Webpacker Not Replacing "process.env" Variables When an Environment Is Specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm relying on Webpacker to convert my `process.env` variables into the actual values when it builds. When I run `bin/rails webpacker:compile` to do this, everything works as expected. Something like this:

```
initialize({apiKey:process.env.MY_API_KEY})
```

... is correctly turned into something like this:

```
initialize({apiKey:"some-api-key-string"})
```

However, when run the same command prefixed with an specific environment (ANY environment), the replacement does NOT work.

Command: `RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails webpacker:compile`

And I'm left with something like this:

```
initialize({apiKey:t.env.MY_API_KEY})
```

My `webpacker.yaml` file contains each environment I specify. In this particular example, it falls back to the default settings:

```
test:
  <<: *default
```

Is there a potentially obvious thing I'm missing here? I've also verified this by running `bin/rails assets:precompile`. When a `RAIS_ENV` is specified, `process.env` strings are not replaced. When the env is left off, it works as expected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where/how is MY_API_KEY set? Are you using something like dotenv-rails?

Comment: Yup, it's set in my `.env` file, and I'm able to reference it just fine using `ENV["MY_API_KEY"]` just fine anywhere else in the application (like printing it into an `.erb` template and grabbing it with JS from the `window` object, which is what I was originally doing before going this route).

Comment: What versions of Webpacker and @rails/webpacker are you on? Is there anything in .env.test? What is MY_API_KEY when you run RAILS_ENV=test rails console?

Comment: Good timing with this comment! It turned out that the value wasn't set in my `.env.test` file, which is why it wasn't being replaced. Thanks for helping out w/ this!

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

As it turns out, it was due to a misunderstanding of how `.env` files were loaded. I had the value defined in my `.env` file, but not in my `.env.test` file. I assumed it would have pulled all values from my `.env` and overwritten them if values also existed in my `.env.test`. But apparently, it didn't bother loading any from the `.env` file at all, which is why I only saw this issue when building assets with a particular `RAILS_ENV` set.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!